# Add values from one object to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, map-function

```
const a1 = [{x:1}, {x:2}],
const a2 = [{y:1}, {y:2}]
```

I want to achieve final result as:

```
a = [{x:1,y:1}, {x:2,y:2}]
```

how do I do this by map method.

Answer (score 2):

```
const a = a1.map((item, index) => {
  return [a1[index], a2[index]];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const a1 = [{
  x: 1
}, {
  x: 2
}];
const a2 = [{
  y: 1
}, {
  y: 2
}];

(function(a1, a2) {
  const ret = a1.map((e, i) => ({ ...e,
    ...a2[i]
  }))
  console.log(ret)
})(a1, a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to use `map` function, maybe is better to use other array methods for better performance and readability. But in this case if you want to use `map` you can iterate one of the arrays and create for each element ("`e`") an object, adding to it the corresponding position/key in the other array and the current one. Something like this:

```
const a = a1.map((e, i) => ({...e, ...a2[i]}))
```